# Issue while trying to set enum data type in MySQL database

Tags: python, python-3.9, django-3.2

**What am I trying to do?**

Django does not support setting enum data type in mysql database. Using below code, I tried to set enum data type.

**Error Details**

> _mysql.connection.query(self, query) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL, `user_id` bigint
> NOT NULL)' at line 1")

**Am I missing anything?**

**Enumeration class with all choices**

```
class enumTokenTypes(models.TextChoices):
    Registration = "Registration"
    ForgotPassword = "Forgot Password"
```

**User Token class in model**

```
class tblusertokens(models.Model):
    token_id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    token_type = EnumField(max_length=20, choices=enumTokenTypes.choices)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = ForeignKey(tblusers, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

**User token create model in migration**

```
class EnumField(CharField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "enum"


migrations.CreateModel(
    name='tblusertokens',
    fields=[
        ('token_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
        ('token_type', clientauth.models.EnumField(choices=[('Registration', 'Registration'), ('Forgot Password', 'Forgotpassword')], max_length=20)),
        ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
        ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='clientauth.tblusers')),
    ],
)
```

**Bounty Question**

set 2 parameters to the function to pass comma separated values and a default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type should be `enum('Registration', 'Forgot Password')` instead of just `enum`.

```py
class EnumField(CharField):

    def db_type(self, connection):
        if connection.vendor == 'mysql':
            return 'enum({0})'.format(','.join("'%s'" % value for value, label in self.choices))
        return super().db_type(connection)
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

## DB default

While not explicitly mentioned in the MySQL 8.0 docs above, you can also specify a DB default.

```py
class EnumField(CharField):

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.db_default = kwargs.pop('db_default', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        if connection.vendor == 'mysql':
            if self.db_default is not None:
                return "enum({0}) DEFAULT '{1}'".format(','.join("'%s'" % value for value, label in self.choices), self.db_default)
            return 'enum({0})'.format(','.join("'%s'" % value for value, label in self.choices))
        return super().db_type(connection)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if self.db_default:
            kwargs['db_default'] = self.db_default
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Usage:

```py
token_type = EnumField(max_length=20, choices=enumTokenTypes.choices, db_default=enumTokenTypes.ForgotPassword)
```

### About `deconstruct()` method

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction:

> The counterpoint to writing your `__init__()` method is writing the `deconstruct()` method. It’s used during model migrations to tell Django how to take an instance of your new field and reduce it to a serialized form - in particular, what arguments to pass to `__init__()` to re-create it.

> If you add a new keyword argument, you need to write code in `deconstruct()` that puts its value into `kwargs` yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can print out the sql for that migration to see specifically whats wrong, but defining `db_type` to return `"enum"` is definitely not the right way to approach it.

```
    ('token_type', CharField(choices=enumTokenTypes.choices, max_length=22)),
```

Does the recommended syntax from the docs on `Enumeration types` not work for you for some reason?

Comment: I want to explicitly set the column datatype - enum but django set the column type varchar which is a kind of confusion as data type.

Comment: There are more differences between the syntax for creating an `enum` column or a `varchar` column than just the keyword though. If you wanted to implement this, you won't be able to subclass CHAR for it- and really, an enum field enforced on the DB isn't much better than one enforced in the app (unless you're accessing the db from outside the app).

Answer (score -1):

**Response to Bounty Question**

*For setting default value*: add the default parameter in EnumField. Below example I have set up enumTokenTypes Registration to be its default value. Look into [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/) for `enum` implementation with examples

```
     class tblusertokens(models.Model):
          token_id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
          token_type = EnumField(max_length=20, choices=enumTokenTypes.choices, default=enumTokenTypes.Registration )
          created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
          user = ForeignKey(tblusers, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```